# Unable to get a certificate from store in c# by common name

Tags: c#, .net, cryptography, x509certificate2

In .Net 4.0 I have been unable to get a certificate from a custom store using the find method of the X509Store. Using the following code:

```
X509Store store = new X509Store(storeName, StoreLocation.CurrentUser);

store.Open(OpenFlags.ReadOnly);
X509Certificate2Collection col = store.Certificates.Find(X509FindType.FindBySubjectName, commonName,false);
```

Comment: Are the certificates definitely in the CurrentUser store rather than the machine store?

Comment: Do you get an exception, or does Find just returns null?

Comment: @ShellShock It will give a collection with 0 items in it and I get an out of bounds exception:Index was out of range. Must be non-negative and less than the size of the collection.
Parameter name: index When I try to use the collection

Comment: @BobVale Yes it shows up the current user store in MMC

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Fixed It**

Sorry I had made a basic mistake I had forgotten to make the private key exportable so the crypto apis would not expose the private key to .net once I made the keys exportable the code began to work.

Comment: Fine, you can accept your own answer after a while. It's a basic mistake all right, but I'm sure there will be plenty others making the same mistake :)